# How to determine if one of my activities is in the foreground then register Broadcast receiver to receive SMS

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, background-foreground

I want the register the Broadcast receiver to receive sms only when my application is in foreground else unregister the Broadcast receiver.

```
<receiver android:name="smsreader.com.messagereciver.IncomingSms">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

//code to receive SMS

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // Get the object of SmsManager
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        try {
        // receive SMS code

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Register your broadcast receiver programmatically in your activity's onPause() {}

Answer (score 1):

This will help you to know if your app is in foreground or not

```
 private boolean isFG;

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    isFG = false;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    isFG = true;
}

// Some function.
public boolean isInForeground() {
    return isFG;
}
```

then write a function to register your `Broadcast receiver` programatically with the following way.

Create a `BroadcastReceiver` in code (MyBroadcastReceiver). Declare `MyBroadcastReceiver` in the scope of your Activity:

```
MyBroadcastReceiver mMyBroadcastReceiver;
```

Register the `BroadcastReceiver` in your Activity by:

```
if(isFG == true){
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED);
this.registerReceiver(mMyBroadcastReceiver, filter);
}else{
//dont register
}
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can register an [ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html) in `onCreate()` method of your `Application` and inside that callbacks count up when an activity is started and down when one is stopped. If count is greater than one, it means at least one activity is started and you can register broadcast receiver, if it is zero, then there is no started (visible to user) activities, and you can unregister broadcast receiver.

This solution is activity independent and will work when any of your activities is started. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you register the broadcast receiver in onResume() in your activity and unregister in onPause().

Like this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
     registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    super.onPause();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created Broadcastreceiver pro-grammatically and registered in onResume() of the Activity also unregistered in onPause() it worked fine in my case.

```
 IncomingSms smsReceiver;
 private IntentFilter myFilter;    



        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            unregisterReceiver(smsReceiver); // UnRegister BroadCastReceiver as you no longer have your activity at Foreground -- Saving CPU & Battery Drainage
            super.onPause();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume()
        {
            smsReceiver = new IncomingSms();
            myFilter = new IntentFilter();
            myFilter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
            registerReceiver(smsReceiver, myFilter); // Register BroadCastReceiver Once again as your activity comes from pause to forground state again.
            super.onResume();
        }
```